# Opening application client from Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Please see the code below:

```
tc.Attributes.Add("onclick", "this.style.backgroundColor='goldenrod'; open('ds://123','_blank','')")
```

tc references TableCell:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tablecell(v=vs.110).aspx

The code opens an application client (person: 123).  However, a new Internet Explorer Window is also opened.  How do I stop the new Internet Explorer window from opening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're explicitly asking for another window to be opened, by calling `window.open`.

Instead, if the `ds:` protocol handler will launch something else anyway, you may just want to assign to `location`, e.g. change

```
open('ds://123','_blank','')
```

to

```
location = 'ds://123';
```

Just check that relative links within the page still work after you've clicked that to launch the client.

If *that* doesn't work, create a zero-height `iframe` and set its `src`:

```
document.getElementById("the-iframe-id").src = "ds://123";
```

Comment: 'Location' has done the trick.  Thanks.  +1.  I will accept once the time limit expires.